# Error when deploy a windows 7 app into emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-build

I developed a app with jquery mobile and compiled it with phonegap build. but when i try to install it to windows 7 emulator i got a error like

Error- Installation of the application failed. Run time error has occurred. Fix the Capabilities in WMAppmanifest.xml File.

Here is my WMAppManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{80a42ce2-0c9f-39d1-a273-bb2e5bdbe855}" Title="PG Build App" 
       RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="0.0.1.0" Genre="apps.normal"  
       Author="xxxxxx@gmail.com" 
       Description="" 
       Publisher="xxxxxx@gmail.com">

    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_HW_FRONTCAMERA" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
    </Capabilities>

    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
    </Tasks>
    <Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="Cordova_1._5._0_Starter1Token" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title>Cordova_1._5._0_Starter1</Title>
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
  </App>
</Deployment>

<!-- WPSDK Version 7.1.7720.0 -->
```

What Capabilities do i need to add here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Phone Capability Detection Tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730(v=VS.92).aspx

You can run it to determine the capabilities of a DLL or Xap files.

Edit:

Here is the default Capabilities when a project is created:

```
 <Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: I didn't find the download link of the tool. can you provide the link to download the CapabilityDetection ?

Comment: Right click on your project - "Open Store test kit" - In the "Automated Tests" press the "Run Tests" button. (I'm using VS 2012)

Comment: But here I'm not using Visual studio just phone-gap build only

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry. Here is the default Capabilities when a new project is created.  Check my first answer.

Comment: Thanks for the default Capabilities. I tried with the default Capabilities but it is showing the same error.